# Weka ARFF How to handle features/attributes that can have more then 1 value per data-item

Tags: machine-learning, weka, arff

For a recommendation engine I am trying to convert my movie data to arff format, and even though the arff format is clear to me I am unsure what the best way is to solve the following problem.

My dataset is going to be in the following (or similar) format where rating is the to be predicted classification variable:

For each user a list of: 
MovieID-Movie Title-year of release-Genre(s)-Actor(s)-Director-Writer(s)-Runtime-Rating

My problem here is the fact that features Genre, Actor, Writers, can have one or multiple entries and weka arff only allows one value for each attribute. A solution for this I though of is:

- Have attributes such as genre0, genre1, genre2. And leave some empty if a movie has for example only 1 genre. The problem I see with this is that this would work great for genre, but does that mean that for the actors for example I'd have to include all actors in the attribute declaration?

  @ATTRIBUTE actor1 {all actors} 
  @ATTRIBUTE actor2 {all actors} 
  @ATTRIBUTE actor3 {all actors}

Since they're all possible values for that specific feature. This approach does make the most sense to me, but since there are thousands of actors, directors and writers this would be rather big attribute declarations.

Is there any better, more efficient, way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way around it, but some preprocessing may help reduce the expected size of the attribute declarations. for example:

{'cruise' : 1, 'smith' : 2}